# How to rotate a log file in ubuntu on size basis hourly?

Tags: 16.04, cron, syslog, logrotate

```
/opt/variable/log/myapp.log
{
    rotate 24
    hourly
    maxsize 10k
    compress
    ifempty
    postrotate
    reload rsyslog > /dev/null 2> & 1 || true
    endscript
}
```

I have copied logrotate from cron.daily to cron.hourly.

Then I executed following commands :

```
sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf

sudo logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Still, it's not working. Any guidance will be much helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: Did you change "logrotate" to "cron.hourly"? It is in "cron.daily" by default

Comment: Yes, I moved the logrotate from cron.daily to cron.hourly

Comment: @Rinzwind I changed my code as following: /opt/mapvariable/logs/mapapp.log
{

        size 100K
        rotate 1
        compress
} and its working when I am executing sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf command. It is not rotating automatically when the size is exceeding so can you please help me. Thanks

Comment: If your `myapp` is generating so much log info that you must rotate hourly, FIX THE APP.

Comment: @waltinator Hey man, thanks But, I want to rotate it when the file reaches 100k. If I rotate it hourly whether it will work on the size basis or on the hourly basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for the question. It is as follows:

In /etc/logrotate.d/ folder I added following lines in the rsysylog file.

```
/opt/variable/logs/myapp.log
{

    maxsize 100K
    minsize 100k
    hourly
    rotate 1
    compress
    postrotate
        service rsyslog rotate >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```

After this, I moved the logrotate file from cron.daily to cron.hourly folder and restarted the computer.
And it started working.

Thank you all for your help and comments.